Why is $x = -3$ at $\frac{2(x-3)(x+3)}{(x+3)^2(x+1)}$ a vertical asymptote instead of a removable discontinuity?
I understand that a vertical asymptote occurs when denominator = 0 and numerator $\neq 0$. A removable discontinuity occurs when both is equal to zero. But, in this video, around 05:48, Sal says that -3 is going to be a vertical asymptote at the expression $\frac{2(x-3)(x+3)}{(x+3)^2(x+1)}$ because $(x+3)$ is squared.
I don't understand. $(-3+3) = 0, (-3+3)(-3+3) = 0$ either way.

Rom428, what did you try in order to solve your problem ? Read this thread and learn how to ask a good question on this site. Your post is being closed because it is a very low-quality question. Moreover, you should learn to use MathJax in order to write formulas in an appropriate manner.

When $x \ne -3$, this is equal to $\frac {2(x - 3)} {(x + 3)(x + 1)}$. You should then be able to see that there are asymptotes at $x = -3$ and $x = -1$.

More generally, a vertical asymptote occurs whenever a linear factor of the denominator has a higher multiplicity than in the numerator. If the multiplicity in the numerator is the same as or higher than the multiplicity in the denominator, then a removable discontinuity (i.e., a "hole" in the graph) occurs

"A removable discontinuity occurs when both is equal to zero" is false.  I think this is the main source of your confusion.

I don't hate this question, especially for a new user.   OP has stated their [mis]understanding (which may be false, but that's learning) and how it is conflicting with an answer, and is asking for clarity.

To be a rat, it must be a mammal.  But being a mammal is not enough to make something a rat.  To be a removable singularity the numerator and denominator must both be $0$, but both being zero is not enough to make something removable.  In this case one pair of the $(x+3)s$ are removable but another still remains that isn't matched with anything.

Notice that $ (x+3)^2 $ is squared, this is equal to the product $(x+3)(x+3)$ so if you divide out the one term of it on top, you are still left with a $(x+3)$ on the bottom and thus you are still going to have a vertical asymptote, and your numerator is -12 so you have a non zero number there, and zero in your denominator. By your own definition, there is a vertical asymptote.

To "remove" a singularity you must "remove one pair of zero terms from top and bottom".  And then you must have what is left.  If what is left also has a "zero term on the bottom but not on top" that zero term is not removed and we are screwed to sunday.
$\require{cancel}$ $\frac{2(x-3)(x+3)}{(x+3)^2(x+1)}=\frac{2(x-3)\color{blue}{(x+3)}}{\color{red}{(x+3)}\color{blue}{(x+3)}(x+1)}=\frac{2(x-3)\cancel{\color{blue}{(x+3)}}}{\color{red}{(x+3)}\cancel{\color{blue}{(x+3)}}(x+1)}=\frac{2(x-3)}{\color{red}{(x+3)}(x+1)}$
In essence.  We did remove a singularity.  And what was left after we removed it  was still a singularity-- an asymptotic singularity.


I understand that a vertical asymptote occurs when denominator${}= 0$ and numerator${}\neq0$. A removable discontinuity occurs when both [are] equal to zero.

This is not true. If the denominator approaches zero and the numerator does not, then you will always get an asymptote, but if both are zero then that's simply not enough information to tell you whether it is a removable discontinuity or not.
There are examples of this that aren't simply a matter of cancelling like terms. For example, $\frac{\sin x}{x^2}$ has an asymptote at $0$. One way to show this is L'Hôpital's rule, which informally says that (providing derivatives exist) differentiating top and bottom gives the same behaviour. Here that gives $\frac{\cos x}{2x}$, which has an asymptote.
